# Accesing XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have xml data that appears in a table in the the format below, everything the same, same number of nodes in each level. The only thing that differs from row to row in the table are the "ID" attribute values and the "Value" node values. What I need is to extract these values from each of these nodes so I can use them in separate where clauses.

```
<ProductVariantAttribute ID="164">
    <ProductVariantAttributeValue>
        <Value>241</Value>
    </ProductVariantAttributeValue>      
</ProductVariantAttribute>

<ProductVariantAttribute ID="443">
    <ProductVariantAttributeValue>
        <Value>1721</Value>
    </ProductVariantAttributeValue>
</ProductVariantAttribute>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it a different way that doesn't use the where joins as was having problems with your code and would have probably taken much longer to run the query. I've ended up comparing a quasi xml string value with the required values pulled from the database beforehand in a where clause so should run much quicker..

Thank you for your help!